# Error query insert from jTextField to table sql

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtextfield

I have problem I add data from 4 JTextField to insert them in table sql 
but it gives me error about the query

this is the code

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/admin";
    String connectionUser = "root";
    String connectionPassword = "123456";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPassword);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO user(id, nom, login, mdp, statut) VALUES ('','"+jTextField2.getText()+ "','" +jTextField4.getText()+"','"+jTextField3.getText()+"','"+jPasswordField1.getText()+"'");

}catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (InstantiationException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

and this is the error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis `VALUES(...` <-- needs a `)`

Comment: **WARN WARN WARN:** your code is prone to sql injection. **Advice:** Use PreparedStatement instead

Comment: I usually develop my queries in Mysql workbench before implementing them in any source code. That way I know the query is correct and gives the desired result. And also as stated above: **Use prepared statements!**

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an ending bracket on your VALUES() from the query.

```
 stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO user(id, nom, login, mdp, statut) VALUES ('','"+jTextField2.getText()+ "','" +jTextField4.getText()+"','"+jTextField3.getText()+"','"+jPasswordField1.getText()+"')");
```

Comment: yes i add it but problem now about id it gives me that:java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column 'id' at row 1

Comment: Thats is because your mysql server is in strict mode, so you can't enter a non-integer into an integer field. I'm not familiar with strict mode, but instead of `''`for the id field, use `NULL` without any quotes, or `0`. Failing that, just don't specify `id` in your column list which is the bet option

Comment: ah great, i'll leave the comment there anyway should someone search

Comment: no i don't write the columnd id in VALUES() because it's auto increment so don't need to write it thank you

Comment: Use null instead of ''. Then way it will auto increase.